# Windows 7 Calculator - how to make it stay on top always

Tags: windows-7, windows, calculator

I'm use the Windows 7 built-in calculator from time to time, and when I use it, I want to make it stay above all the other windows, so I can see the numbers and copy them, etc to other applications.  How can I do this?

**Other** than putting the windows side-by-side please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.abstractpath.com/powermenu/ It works. That is all.

Comment: nvidia and ati have bundled some desktop-helpers with their drivers which achieve the same (just a hint), nevertheless +1

Answer (score 4):

As listed in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/7271/most-useful-autohotkey-scripts/32045#32045) answer for another question. You can use autohotkey which is loved by a lot of users.

> Toggle the active window topmost status (always on top):

```
^+t::
      WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle,A
return
```

Comment: I've actually not used autohotkey much, so I'm unfamiliar with the code...how does this code work?  do I just create a new script, copy and paste this into the script config, and then what?  a little confused here...

Comment: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Tutorial.htm  Because they can say it so much easier lol